# Validate jquery - isset($_POST. Still showing error

Tags: php, jquery

When clicking submit button showing message "Error...3" which came from email.
how this happen.

Comment: have you tried print_r($_POST)?

Comment: Ya showing nothing.

Comment: can you show your js code to collect the form elements for instance the point where you collect firstname to that's a variable.

Comment: updated my question @Dave

Comment: thanks that looks fine you could try doing a console.log(email) to see what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$_POST["email"]` instead of `$_POST["em"]`, Where `email` is the **name** of the input field.

It goes same for all other input fields.

```
$_POST["firstname"];
$_POST["usernamer"];
$_POST["passwordr"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Your $_POST data does not match the names in the form, they should be:

```
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"] != '') $em = $this->db1->e($_POST["email"]);
if (isset($_POST["firstname"]) && $_POST["firstname"] != '') $fn = $this->db1->e($_POST["firstname"]);
if (isset($_POST["usernamer"]) && $_POST["usernamer"] != '') $un = $this->db1->e($_POST["usernamer"]);
if (isset($_POST["passwordr"]) && $_POST["passwordr"] != '') $pw = $this->db1->e($_POST["passwordr"]);
```